# How to set the Mapview's width and height in java code?

Tags: android, width, android-mapview, classcastexception, layoutparams

I try to set the width and height in java code as below:

```
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams params=new LayoutParams(500,200);
 mMapView.setLayoutParams(params);
 mMapView.invalidate();
```

but some error occurs when execute the code:

```
02-02 06:04:20.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1043): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params=new LayoutParams(500,200);
```

to

```
com.google.android.maps.MapView.LayoutParams params=new com.google.android.maps.MapView.LayoutParams(500,200);
```

Comment: thank you , but this api is not found in package com.google.android.maps.MapView.LayoutParams and I try to change it to[com.google.android.maps.MapView.LayoutParams params = new MapView.LayoutParams(500, 200, null, MapView.LayoutParams.CENTER);] , but it still the same error. I don't know why this error is occured .It is really a problem to solve this problem.....

Comment: Are you setting your Android build target as one of the Google APIs? Otherwise it will error because the standard build targets don't include Maps.

Answer (score 0):

If you just do `mMapView.setLayoutParams(new MapView.LayoutParams(500, 200, null, MapView.LayoutParams.CENTER));` it should work. When I do this for my map, I get no errors.

Hope it works out for you.